# Grohe shower controller turns itself on at various times

Tags: plumbing

Grohe shower controller turns itself on at various times, day or night. Not full on, but enough to hear and see. Cartridge # 47080000 was replaced by a plumber, but did not solve the problem completely. What could be causing this?

Comment: A photo might help

Comment: Contact Grohe customer support. They are usually very good with helping work out issues.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact Grohe's customer support. I will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I take it this is a new problem. There's a chance that your area had low pressure and the water company raised it and now your pressure is too high. Mosy plumbing fixtures are designed to handle 80 PSI or less. Pressure greater than that can cause leaking faucets either through the seals or forcing open the cartridge. Raising the water heater temperature can also raise the pressure in the system and can cause leaky faucets until the pressure is released by turning on the faucet. Get a water pressure gauge from your home store, costs about 12 bucks and monitor your pressure. If it happens to be high, you might think about installing a pressure regualtor.

Comment: Thank you for your pressure suggestion. I have a pressure guage, so I will take a reading at an exterior hose bib and see what it reads. I will post as soon as I get to the apartment sometime this week.